# Jupyter Notebook won't run python 3 - import pygments error

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

New to Anaconda and Jupyter Notebooks but for some reason I can't run Jupyter Notebook in my environments running python 3. Every time my terminal displays this:

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in 
>       sys.exit(main())
>
> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
>       return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
>
> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
>       app.initialize(argv)
>
> File "", line 2, in initialize
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1296, in initialize
>       self.init_webapp()
>
> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1093, in init_webapp
>       self.jinja_environment_options
>
> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 167, in **init**
>       default_url, settings_overrides, jinja_env_options)
>
> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 259, in init_settings
>       nbextensions_path=jupyter_app.nbextensions_path,
>
> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 807, in nbextensions_path
>       from IPython.paths import get_ipython_dir
>
> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/**init**.py", line 54, in 
>       from .core.application import Application
>
> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 25, in 
>       from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
>
> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 27, in 
>       from IPython.core import ultratb
>
> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 115, in 
>       from IPython.core import debugger
>
> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/debugger.py", line 37, in 
>       from IPython.utils import PyColorize
>
> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/utils/PyColorize.py", line 47, in 
>       from .colorable import Colorable
>
> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/utils/colorable.py", line 12, in 
>       import pygments
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygments/**init**.py", line 46
>       except TypeError, err:
>                       ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Any recommendations on how to correct?

Comment: Last line indicates that `pygments` is imported from Python 2.7 (system install?), this is likely the source of your problem. This should not be loaded from Anaconda. Did you change anything in your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of... how would I go about changing it back?

Comment: First check if it contains `/Library/Python/2.7/` when you display it `echo $PYTHONPATH`